# Foreach for arrays inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array and i did a print_r of it and it returned this...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 2 [client] => Test 1 [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [paymenttimeallotment] => 15 [clientid] => 1 [date] => 2012-04-12 [enddate] => 2012-04-02 00:00:00 [total] => 250.86 [remainingbalance] => 250.86 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => Not distributed [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [invoiceid] => 1 [client] => Test 1 [invoicedeliverymethod] => email [paymenttimeallotment] => 15 [clientid] => 1 [date] => 2012-04-12 [enddate] => 2012-03-31 23:59:59 [total] => 602.29 [remainingbalance] => 602.29 [ispaid] => No [isagentpaid] => No [datedistributed] => 2012-04-12 [invoicedcontact] => 1 ) )
```

I tried to run this code...

```
 foreach($resultArray as $row => $value){
    echo $value . "<br/>";
}
```

and that returned Array Array.

How do I get the values inside of these arrays?

Comment: this is an example of nested array.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to iterate the elements from the inside array, like this:

```
foreach($resultArray as $row => $innerArray){
  foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
    echo $value . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't access the keys of nested array. I don't understand, why do I need two foreach loops. Why just not foreach:

foreach($arr as $val) { 

print($val['key'];

}

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu this is old but for somebody that's looking at this... you can do foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) { print($arr[$key]; } for the second level values without having to loop a second time.

Answer (score 11):

```
foreach($resultArray as $row => $value){
    foreach($value as $row2 => $value2)
        echo $value2 . "<br/>";
}
```