# How do I Store an Array Variable Inside of Another Array Variable using while loop and for each?

Tags: foreach, while-loop

How do I Store an Array Variable Inside of Another Array Variable using while loop and for each?

[Like this(array inside array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu2nn.jpg)

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Your question is confusing. If you want to print an array you can use print_r($array). Please be clear with your question

Comment: I want to print array like in image which i have upload in question

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu2nn.jpg This is the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please chec [Foreach for arrays inside of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131802/foreach-for-arrays-inside-of-an-array)

```
foreach($resultArray as $row => $innerArray){
  foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
    echo $value . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

also check this link : [Foreach for arrays inside of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684463/php-foreach-with-nested-array)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

```
   <?php
    $format = array('Roman' =>  array('one'=>'I','two'=>'II'),
    'Arbic' =>  array('one'=>'1','two'=>'2'));
    while (list($key, $value) = each($format)) {
           echo $value;
    foreach( $key as $key1 => $value1)   {
    echo $key1 .'='.$value1;
    }

    ?>
```

I have not tested .

Comment: I have shared this answer to print your array using while and foreach loop