# Convert one array to another in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have array like this

```
$array =  (
            [customer] => Array
                (
                    [emailAddress] => test@gmail.com
                )

            [recommendationProductDetails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [productId] => 7053
                            [title] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                            [imageWebAddress] => http://Image/GetImage/6118
                            [webAddress] => http://Shop/Product?name=AG%20Termopasty%20silikonska%20termalna%20pasta%20tuba%207gr&accountingCode=8703
                            [description] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [productId] => 4610
                            [title] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                            [imageWebAddress] => http://Image/GetImage/6118
                            [webAddress] => http://Shop/Product?name=AG%20Termopasty%20silikonska%20termalna%20pasta%20tuba%207gr&accountingCode=8703
                            [description] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [productId] => 4591
                            [title] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                            [imageWebAddress] => http://Image/GetImage/6118
                            [webAddress] => http://Shop/Product?name=AG%20Termopasty%20silikonska%20termalna%20pasta%20tuba%207gr&accountingCode=8703
                            [description] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [productId] => 1756
                            [title] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                            [imageWebAddress] => http://Image/GetImage/6118
                            [webAddress] => http://Shop/Product?name=AG%20Termopasty%20silikonska%20termalna%20pasta%20tuba%207gr&accountingCode=8703
                            [description] => silikonska termalna pasta tuba 7gr
                        )

                )

        )
```

I need to get new array that will look like this

```
    $newArray = [7053, 4610, 4591, 1756];
```

I have tried a lot of solution from this question
[Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494953/is-there-a-function-to-extract-a-column-from-an-array-in-php)
But i have no luck, also i have tried to foreach all like this

```
    foreach($array as $row => $innerArray){
        foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
          print_r($value) . "<br/>";
        }
      }
```

But this way i got only display of results, also i have tried answers from this question
[Foreach for arrays inside of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131802/foreach-for-arrays-inside-of-an-array)

After all that i didnt manage to get proper new array, can somebody help me pleae, because I am not so good at php. Thanks in advance

Also i have tried

```
foreach ($dataRecommend as $item) {
    $namearray[] = $item['recommendationProductDetails'];
}

foreach ($namearray as $item) {
    $productArray[] = $item['productId'];
}
print_r($productArray);
```

Also i made it like this

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $namearray[] = $item['recommendationProductDetails'];
}
for($i = 0, $l = 4; $i < $l; ++$i) {
    foreach ($namearray as $item) {
 $productArray[] = $item[$i]['productId'];
 }
  }

print_r($productArray);
```

But i dont see this is good :(

Comment: Create a new empty array. Then instead of displaying the results, add the results to that new array.

Comment: `foreach` through `$array[recommendationProductDetails]` and add the value of `productId` to a new array

Comment: _“I have tried a lot of solution from this question”_ - then _show us_ what you actually tried, instead of just going “no luck”. (And please provide example data as a `var_export` in cases like this, so that everyone can simply copy&paste it to get _working_ code right away.)

Comment: Why are you so stricted, i told you i have looked answers but I dont know how to implement those answers in  my code :(

Comment: @CBroe If you know simple answer maybe you can help me, because as i said I am not so good in PHP, if you want ot help me?

Comment: You said you _tried_ something, so you should _show us_ what you actually tried - as [ask] explains. Just going “I tried a bunch of stuff, but it all did not work” is _not_ a proper way to ask here on this site to begin with. _“If you know simple answer”_ - the simple answer is in what you already found - `array_column`.

Comment: @CBroe I have added edit what i have tried

Comment: @kerbh0lz Can you please make answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function to extract a 'column' from an array in PHP?

Yes, there is `array_column(array $input, mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = NULL])` [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

So in your code: `array_column($array['recommendationProductDetails'], 'productId');`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: recommendationProductDetails

Comment: @MiomirDancevic then your `$array` appears to be something different, than what you have shown us as example data above.

Comment: This comes from $array = json_decode( $bodyRecommend, true);

Comment: It doesn’t matter where it comes from, what matters is what the structure actually is. And according to what you have shown in your question, this should work. If it doesn’t - then your data must be somehow different from what you have shown us.

Comment: I have updated my question, and found stupid solution that work, can you please help me refactor

Answer (score 0):

array_column(array $input, mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = NULL]) doc

array_column($array['recommendationProductDetails'], 'productId');

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` to iterate over every item in `$array['recommendationProductDetails']`. `$newArray` will hold the extracted values:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array['recommendationProductDetails'] as $arrayItem) {
    array_push($newArray, $arrayItem['productId']);
}
print_r($newArray);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7053
    [1] => 4610
    [2] => 4591
    [3] => 1756
)
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in